# How to check all opened windows with title in chrome using selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, automation

In chrome 3 windows opened but without closing any window need to check last open window title
tried driver.getTitle();
but It returns first window title
Reason is that I want get page title and performing any activity on last window.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you can switch the window and then validate page. You can try this approach:

```
public void switchwindow() throws InterruptedException {
        currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));

        Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String handle : allHandles) {
            if (!handle.equals(currentHandle)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(handle);
                break;
            } else {
                driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);
                Thread.sleep(8000);
            }

        }
    }
```

Switch to parent window:

```
public void switchToParentWindow() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);
    }
```